# How to link two datepicker so that the begin date on the first datepicker is the minimum date on the second datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, getuikit

I am using UIKit web framework (getuikit.com)

Is there any way I can use two datepickers so that the selected begin date in the first would match the minimum date allowed on the second datepicker? (essentially to make it work like hotel/flight booking)

Here is what I've tried in JQuery:

```
$("#startDate").blur(function() {
  var init = $("#startDate").val();
$("#endDate").attr("data-uk-datepicker","format:'DD/MM/YYYY', minDate:"+init+", maxDate:10");
  UIkit.datepicker("#endDate");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use the `hide.uk.datepicker` event instead of jQuery's blur.

Note that maxDate:10 only gives you the offset in days from current date.

Then you could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<form class="uk-form">
        <input type="" id="startDate" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'DD/MM/YYYY'}">
        <input type="" id="endDate">
    </form>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
    jQuery("#startDate").on("hide.uk.datepicker", function (event) 
    {
        var init = jQuery(this).val();
        var dateArray = init.split("/");

        var day = parseFloat(dateArray[0]);
        var month = parseFloat(dateArray[1]);
        var year = parseFloat(dateArray[2]);

        var newDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year,month - 1,day));

        //add 10 days
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 10);

        var newDay = newDate.getDate();
        var newMonth = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
        var newYear = newDate.getFullYear();

        var formatedDate = newDay + "." + newMonth + "." + newYear;

        UIkit.datepicker("#endDate", {format:"DD/MM/YYYY", minDate:init, maxDate:formatedDate});
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.uk-datepicker-date-disabled
{
    color: gray;
}
```

It should look like this:
[image]

Comment: this one did the trick, but it seems to render only once. should I use update.uk.datepicker? and where?

Answer (score 0):

> Here is what you want :
>   you can customise the code as your app!

```js
     var $inDate = $("[name=outDate]");
    var $outDate = $("[name=inDate]");

$outDate.datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShow : function(input, inst){
                if($inDate.is(input)){
                    var fromDate = $outDate.datepicker("getDate");
                    if(fromDate == null){
                        $outDate.datepicker("setDate", new Date());
                        fromDate  = new Date();
                    }
                    fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
                    inst.settings.minDate = fromDate;
                }
        },
        onSelect: function(dataText, inst){
                if($outDate.is(inst.input)){
                        var fromDate = $outDate.datepicker("getDate");
                        var toDate = $inDate.datepicker("getDate");
                        if(toDate && fromDate.getTime()>=toDate.getTime()){
                                toDate.setTime(fromDate.getTime());
                                toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()+1);
                                $inDate.datepicker("setDate", toDate);     
                        }
                }
        },
      
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<small class="labelFlightForm">Check-in Date</small><br />
<input type="text" name="inDate"class="form-control input-sm datepicker" id="datepicker"><br />
                 
<small class="labelFlightForm">Check-out Date</small><br />
  <input type="text" name="outDate" class="form-control input-sm datepicker"  id="returnDatepicker">
```

Answer (score 0):

@eaCe Answer was great, but I believe that the changes renders only once.

Instead of :
`UIkit.datepicker("#endDate", {format:"DD/MM/YYYY", minDate:init, maxDate:formatedDate});` use options property : `dateFrom.options.maxDate = formatedDate;`

you can do this

```
//Init the datePicker first
let endDate= UIkit.datepicker("#endDate", {format:"DD.MM.YYYY"})
/**
** Rest of code
*/
//at the end, Update your minDate or maxDate using the options property
endDate.options.maxDate = formatedDate
```

Your code should look like this afterwards.

```
    jQuery("#startDate").on("hide.uk.datepicker", function (event) 
    {
       let endDate= UIkit.datepicker("#endDate", {format:"DD/MM/YYYY"}); 
        var init = jQuery(this).val();
        var dateArray = init.split("/");

        var day = parseFloat(dateArray[0]);
        var month = parseFloat(dateArray[1]);
        var year = parseFloat(dateArray[2]);

        var newDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year,month - 1,day));

        //add 10 days
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 10);

        var newDay = newDate.getDate();
        var newMonth = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
        var newYear = newDate.getFullYear();

        var formatedDate = newDay + "." + newMonth + "." + newYear; //Maybe you should replace the '.' wih '/' since you 're using a DD/MM/YYYY format.
        endDate.options.mixDate = init;
        endDate.options.maxDate = formatedDate;
        endDate.options.maxDate = init ? formatedDate : false //in case no value , better give maxDate false
    });
```